# How to connect to Microsoft SQL Server from Python code?

Tags: python, sql-server, docker, pyodbc

I am trying to run [Microsoft SQL Server in Docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server) and connect to it via Python with `pyodbc`.

It is the first time I am working with this database and drives me nuts because it killed my system 5 times in a row and I don't understand how to configure a simple connection.

The way I run the database:

```
docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=mySecretPassword1234567890' -p 1433:1433 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
```

I use this code to connect:

```
import pyodbc

conn_str = (
    r"Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};"
    r"Server=127.0.0.1;"
    r"Database=testdb;"
    r"UID=sa;"
    r"PWD=mySecretPassword1234567890;"
    r"Trusted_Connection=yes;"
)
conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
```

`odbcinst` details:

```
$ odbcinst -j
unixODBC 2.3.7
DRIVERS............: /usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /usr/local/etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /usr/local/etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /Users/dmytro/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

Debug trace from ODBC driver:

```
[ODBC][23857][1592579186.233946][__handles.c][460]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
            Environment = 0x7fc1a9973e00
[ODBC][23857][1592579186.233981][SQLSetEnvAttr.c][189]
        Entry:
            Environment = 0x7fc1a9973e00
            Attribute = SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION
            Value = 0x3
            StrLen = 4
[ODBC][23857][1592579186.234005][SQLSetEnvAttr.c][381]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
[ODBC][23857][1592579186.234024][SQLAllocHandle.c][377]
        Entry:
            Handle Type = 2
            Input Handle = 0x7fc1a9973e00
[ODBC][23857][1592579186.234044][SQLAllocHandle.c][493]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
            Output Handle = 0x7fc1a997ae00
[ODBC][23857][1592579186.234321][SQLDriverConnectW.c][290]
        Entry:
            Connection = 0x7fc1a997ae00
            Window Hdl = 0x0
            Str In = [Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=127.0.0.1;Database=testdb;UID=sa;PWD=mySecretPassword1234567890;Trusted_Connectio...][length = 133 (SQL_NTS)]
            Str Out = 0x0
            Str Out Max = 0
            Str Out Ptr = 0x0
            Completion = 0
        UNICODE Using encoding ASCII 'UTF-8' and UNICODE 'UCS-2-INTERNAL'

[ODBC][23857][1592579186.234896][SQLConnect.c][1138]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found
[ODBC][23857][1592579186.234929][SQLDriverConnect.c][748]
        Entry:
            Connection = 0x7fc1a997ae00
            Window Hdl = 0x0
            Str In = [Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=127.0.0.1;Database=testdb;UID=sa;PWD=**************************;Trusted_Connection...][length = 133 (SQL_NTS)]
            Str Out = 0x7ffeef507600
            Str Out Max = 2048
            Str Out Ptr = 0x0
            Completion = 0
[ODBC][23857][1592579186.235105][SQLConnect.c][1138]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found
[ODBC][23857][1592579186.235134][SQLGetDiagRecW.c][535]
        Entry:
            Connection = 0x7fc1a997ae00
            Rec Number = 1
            SQLState = 0x7ffeef5099a4
            Native = 0x7ffeef509194
            Message Text = 0x7ffeef5091a0
            Buffer Length = 1023
            Text Len Ptr = 0x7ffeef50919e
[ODBC][23857][1592579186.235160][SQLGetDiagRecW.c][596]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
            SQLState = [01000]
            Native = 0x7ffeef509194 -> 0
            Message Text = [[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found]
[ODBC][23857][1592579186.235205][SQLFreeHandle.c][290]
        Entry:
            Handle Type = 2
            Input Handle = 0x7fc1a997ae00
[ODBC][23857][1592579186.235224][SQLFreeHandle.c][339]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
```

I read through docs and searched answers in StackOverflow but so far I cannot get it. How can I debug it further?

Important: I cannot switch from the Docker approach of running Microsoft SQL Server and I cannot switch to a different database as well.

Comment: it's throwing the following error several times > Can't open lib `'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found` and try to see the podbc drivers available `pyodbc.drivers()`

Comment: @abestrad it is just empty. What should I do in this case?

Comment: `pip install pyodbc` and check `pyodbc.drivers()` again. It should show a list like  >>>  `pyodbc.drivers()
['SQL Server', 'Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)', 'Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)', 'Microsoft Access dBASE Driver (*.dbf, *.ndx, *.mdx)', 'Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)', 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server', 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server', 'SQL Server Native Client 11.0', 'SQL Server Native Client RDA 11.0'] `

Comment: @abestrad This is exactly the problem, it is installed but I still don't get any drivers. Is it a bug in `pyodbc`?

Comment: Did you see  any of the following messages?  > `Collecting pyodbc
  > Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/........./pyodbc-4.......whl (61kB)  > Installing collected packages: pyodbc
Successfully installed pyodbc-` That's going to help you to track the problem. It might be an issue with pip and not pyodbc.

Comment: I am using `poetry` not directly `pip`. Do you think it may be related? Also, I am using Linux, not Windows laptop.

Comment: Does your `/usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini` file contain an entry for [ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server] ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It came out that the problem was with drivers. `pyodbc.drivers()` returned an empty list. In order to communicate between Micorosft SQL Server and Python you need extra [ODBC driver layer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

Thank you to @abestrad who pointed out this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pyodbc

conn_str = (
    r"Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};"
    r"Server=host.docker.internal;"
    r"Database=testdb;"
    r"UID=sa;"
    r"PWD=mySecretPassword1234567890;"
    r"Trusted_Connection=yes;"
)
conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
```